# insert with multiple select statements and php variables

Tags: php, mysql

I want to insert record in product table from two tables i.e adminlogin and product_category and with few php variables.my query is not working giving syntax error..please help

```
$sSQL4 = 
"INSERT INTO product(user_id,category_id,product_id,title,price,product_img,product_status) Select admin_id from adminlogin where username='" .$user_name. "',
 SELECT category_id,'',
'" .$title. "',
'" .$price. "',
'" .$file_name1. "',
'pending' from product_category WHERE category_name='" .$category. "'";
$result4= mysql_query($sSQL4);
```

Comment: Please, before you write **any** more SQL interfacing code, you must read up on [proper SQL escaping](http://bobby-tables.com/php) to avoid severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). Also, `mysql_query` should not be used in new applications. It's a deprecated interface that's being removed from future versions of PHP. A modern replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) and will make your database code easier to get right.

Comment: Or alternatively you can also use the [MySQLi interface](http://www.php.net/mysqli). Works just fine as well

Comment: try to do echo `$sSQL4;`  and then tell me what does it show you?

Comment: General tip: If you get an error message, TELL US what it is. Don't make us guess. Plus, your SQL is totally broken. `INSERT ... SELECT ... SELECT` is not a valid query.

Comment: echo sSQL4 shows INSERT INTO product(user_id,category_id,product_id,title,price,product_img,product_status) Select admin_id from adminlogin where username='madeeha', SELECT category_id,'','aasha','333','Hydrangeas.jpg','pending' from product_category WHERE category_name='mobile'

Comment: I believe you want to do an `UPDATE` and not a `INSERT/SELECT` when using the `WHERE` clause. @madeehanaiyar - As Marc said, your query is invalid.

Comment: no. i want to insert data in product table by selecting specific data from adminlogin and product_category @fred

Answer (score 0):

The reason you're getting a syntax error is because you're not using valid SQL. The INSERT INTO ... SELECT syntax only works with a SINGLE select query.

Currently, you're basically linking 2 completely random queries, and mysql hasn't the slightest clue how to link them (even if it were possible).

What you want instead, is either to do 2 queries:
1. A query to get the username
2. The query to insert... select, while adding the username as a static string yourself.

Alternatively, you can use a sub-query to add the username. However, since the subquery is repeated for every single row inserted, this is actually a lot slower(!).

With a subquery, your query would look like:

```
$sSQL4 = "INSERT INTO product(user_id,category_id,product_id,title,price,product_img,product_status) SELECT (SELECT admin_id from adminlogin WHERE username='" .$user_name. "'), category_id,'','" .$title. "','" .$price. "','" .$file_name1. "','pending' FROM product_category WHERE category_name='" .$category. "'";

$result4 = mysql_query($sSQL4);
```

With 2 queries, you would get something like:

```
$q = mysql_query("SELECT admin_id FROM adminlogin WHERE username='" . $user_name . "'");
$adminId = mysql_fetch_object($q)->admin_id;

$sSQL4 = "INSERT INTO product(user_id,category_id,product_id,title,price,product_img,product_status) SELECT '".$adminId."', category_id,'','" .$title. "','" .$price. "','" .$file_name1. "','pending' FROM product_category WHERE category_name='" .$category. "'";
```

Comment: thank @Tularis.my problem is solved with your syntax.

Answer (score 0):

You are using wrong syntax. Use 'INSERT INTO(col1,col2) Values(val1,val2)'